# when using houdini Ubuntu crashes after the simulation is done

Tags: dual-boot, suspend, hibernate

My motherboard shows a gpu light on it, after the crash(or whatever its doing) never had any issues in windows(dual boot system). I have a 7950x 128gb of ram and a 4090. I have plenty of power(1200w psu). Tried turning off hibernation and sleeping etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated.